# How to pass a System.Linq.LambdaExpression?

Tags: .net, lambda, expression-trees

I have a method like this:

```
public List<MyObjects> All<TEntity>(params LambdaExpression[] exprs)
```

with the intention that I can call it like this:

```
All<SomeObject>(a => a.Collection1, a=> a.Collection2, a=>a.Collection3);
```

However, my method signature does not appear to take the expression correctly. What am I doing wrong? How would I write the method signature to get the desired effect?

edited: I realized that my example method call wasn't accurately reflecting what I was trying to do in real life :)

thanks!!

Comment: What is the `All()` method supposed to be doing?  Is it suppose to check if items in a collection satisfy a set of predicates (similar to the LINQ [`All()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) method)?  Or is it flattening a set of collections into one collection (similar to the LINQ [`SelectMany()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) method)?  It sounds like you should just be using `SelectMany()` here if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the cleanest way in this case would be to write an extension method.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static List<TEntity> All<TEntity, TResult>(
        this TEntity entity,
        params Func<TEntity, TResult>[] exprs)
    {
        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }
        if (exprs == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("exprs");
        }

        // TODO: Implementation required
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note that you don't have to specify type arguments when you're calling the method because of the type inference.

```
class C
{
    public List<string> Collection1 {get; set;}
    public List<string> Collection2 {get; set;}
    public List<string> Collection3 {get; set;}
    // ...
}
// ...
var c = new C();            
c.All(x => x.Collection1, x => x.Collection2, x => x.Collection3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you meant something like

```
public List<MyObjects> All(params Action<ICollection>[] exprs)

All(a => new List<int>(), b => new List<string>(), c => new List<bool>());
```

Comment: that's not quite it - because I need to access the properties of the "a" object passed into the expression. Isn't the Action class part of the MVC framework? This isn't connected to MVC.